# How to split string in python

Tags: python, split, pulp

I am trying to display the result that has been solved using a problem solver of pulp

so I used for loop command to display all optimal slotuin

```
  for vi in prob.variables():
            if vi.varValue == 1:
                print(vi.name)
```

and this a sample from the output

Days_1_7251___MLK

Days_1_7251___NTI

Days_1_7269___MED

Days_1_7271___MED

Days_1_7271___MLK

Days_1_7271___RCO

**What I need**
is to split the result and get the value after the second underscore

EX:

Orginal output: Days_1_7271___MLK

The value after extracting : 7271___MLK

I tried the below command to split, but I got only the number (7271)

`vi.name.split("_")[2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`maxsplit`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html#syntax) argument with `split()` to only split till second `_`:

```
x = "Days_1_7251___MLK"
data = x.split('_', maxsplit=2)[-1] # 7251___MLK
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work in that case

```
"_".join(vi.name.split("_")[2:])
```